# Differing tokens from AWS CLI vs API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

When using the AWS CLI command of `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1` I get a reasonably sized token to use with my Docker commands. Using the API however generates a much larger token that is invalid and causes a 400 error when attempting to have Docker login.

```
var ecrClient = new AmazonECRClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var tokenResponse = await ecrClient.GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(new GetAuthorizationTokenRequest());
var token = tokenResponse.AuthorizationData.Single().AuthorizationToken;
```

the `awsAccessKeyId` and `awsSecretAccessKey` are both identical from the API usage to the CLI usage (when doing `aws configure` and setting them there). Documentation for the API is a bit sparse, what am I missing (or misunderstanding)?

Comment: `get-login-password` and `get-authorization-token` are two different API calls with different purposes. Why are you using the first one in CLI and the second in your c#?

Comment: @Marcin because the documentation for .GetAuthorizationTokenAsync implies that it's the API version of get-login-password (and if that's the wrong reading of the reference doc, then they should probably remove the references to the CLI command in that method description or better clarify what you need to do).

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/ECR/MECRGetAuthorizationTokenAsyncGetAuthorizationTokenRequestCancellationToken.html for the reference I am referring to

Comment: I see, you are right. Did you follow the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html#registry_auth_http) on how to use this api?

Comment: @Marcin with the CLI command, I was able to just pass the token to docker login successfully without anything else (only other args were username and the ending that it's logging into). I expected that I'd be able to do the same with the token provided by the API, in fact I expected to get the same token, but I get a vastly larger one and it fails to work. If I need to do something different with the API token, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, its different. In the link I provided there are instructions what to do. You have to use `curl` or whatever is equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the response from the API is Base64Encoded (it does actually say that in the docs, I just assumed that the token from the CLI was also encoded and that I didn't need to decode it, just pass it along as given).

Decoding it via:

```
var tokenData = Convert.FromBase64String(tokenResponse.AuthorizationData.Single().AuthorizationToken);
var tokenContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tokenData);
```

Returns a string in the format of `Foo:bar` where `bar` is the token that matches the return from the CLI. So splitting it on the colon then provides you the same information you would via the CLI.